# Accept a specific domain name for the email to sign in on Web2py

Tags: web2py, email-validation

As I said in the title I want to accept only specific addresses for sign in on my website.

I try this:

`address_in_2_parts=auth.user.email.split("@")
if address_in_2_parts[1]=="domain_i_want.com"`

I want to add condition but where I have to add this lines of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an additional validator to the `email` field of the `db.auth_user` table. In the model file where `Auth` is defined, *after* calling `auth.define_tables()`, add the following:

```
db.auth_user.email.requires.append(IS_MATCH(r'.*@domain_i_want\.com$',
    error_message='Only domain_i_want.com email addresses allowed.'))
```